# Encrypt data by RSA

Tags: c#, public-key-encryption

I used these 2 methods for encrypt and decrypt string value by RSA keys (public and private)

```
public string EncryptString( string inputString, int dwKeySize, string xmlString )
{
    // TODO: Add Proper Exception Handlers
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider( dwKeySize );
    rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString( xmlString );
    int keySize = dwKeySize / 8;
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes( inputString );
    // The hash function in use by the .NET RSACryptoServiceProvider here is SHA1
    // int maxLength = ( keySize ) - 2 - ( 2 * SHA1.Create().ComputeHash( rawBytes ).Length );
    int maxLength = keySize - 42;
    int dataLength = bytes.Length;
    int iterations = dataLength / maxLength;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for( int i = 0; i <= iterations; i++ )
    {
        byte[] tempBytes = new byte[ ( dataLength - maxLength * i > maxLength ) ? maxLength : dataLength - maxLength * i ];
        Buffer.BlockCopy( bytes, maxLength * i, tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length );
        byte[] encryptedBytes = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt( tempBytes, true );
        // Be aware the RSACryptoServiceProvider reverses the order of encrypted bytes after encryption and before decryption.
        // If you do not require compatibility with Microsoft Cryptographic API (CAPI) and/or other vendors.
        // Comment out the next line and the corresponding one in the DecryptString function.
        Array.Reverse( encryptedBytes );
        // Why convert to base 64?
        // Because it is the largest power-of-two base printable using only ASCII characters
        stringBuilder.Append( Convert.ToBase64String( encryptedBytes ) );               
    }           
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

public string DecryptString( string inputString, int dwKeySize, string xmlString )
{
    // TODO: Add Proper Exception Handlers
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider( dwKeySize );
    rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString( xmlString );
    int base64BlockSize = ( ( dwKeySize / 8 ) % 3 != 0 ) ? ( ( ( dwKeySize / 8 ) / 3 ) * 4 ) + 4 : ( ( dwKeySize / 8 ) / 3 ) * 4;
    int iterations = inputString.Length / base64BlockSize;
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    for( int i = 0; i < iterations; i++ )
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String( inputString.Substring( base64BlockSize * i, base64BlockSize ) );
        // Be aware the RSACryptoServiceProvider reverses the order of encrypted bytes after encryption and before decryption.
        // If you do not require compatibility with Microsoft Cryptographic API (CAPI) and/or other vendors.
        // Comment out the next line and the corresponding one in the EncryptString function.
        Array.Reverse( encryptedBytes );
        arrayList.AddRange( rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt( encryptedBytes, true ) );             
    }           
    return Encoding.UTF32.GetString( arrayList.ToArray( Type.GetType( "System.Byte" ) ) as byte[] );
}
```

but when I encrypt some text by public key, the encrypted text will be so long. for example when I encrypt 280 character, the encrypted text will be about 2500 character!! and its so long... is there any better way? I want to send the encrypted text by sms to another phone, so its better to be short as same as 3 message. any Ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using the .NET frameworks own [RSA class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.aspx)? Generally it's bad practice to write your own implementation unless you know a lot about side channel attacks (or are doing a homework).

Comment: @AdamHarwood I used RSACryptoServiceProvider class that inherited RSA class. do u have any sample of that?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like you're talking about compressing the output of your RSA encryption. If so, then this is possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955414/encrypted-data-length-is-very-large-with-rsa

Comment: Why are you using UTF32?